# p2p connect parameters

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

The following is the Start P2P group formation with a discovered P2P peer. This includes
optional group owner negotiation, group interface setup, provisioning, and establishing data connection.

```
p2p_connect <peer device address> <pbc|pin|PIN#> [label|display|keypad
[persistent] [join|auth] [go_intent=<0..15>] [freq=<in MHz>]
```

The  parameter specifies the WPS provisioning method.

I want to reach this specification in android.net.wifi.p2p 
Where i can find it?

Comment: have you tried reading [Connecting with Wi-Fi Direct](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)?

Comment: This is what i want to reach .. i.e. the source code of it

Comment: source of code of what? the example or the `WifiP2pManager`? have you found anything useful in the API sample code?

Comment: i mean the source code of the place  where they specify the paramters mentioned in the above question in android.net.wifi.p2p                         so i can edit these paramters

Answer (score 0):

The Android source code can be found here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/

The package that you are looking for seems to be located at wifi.p2p (so without the android.net prefix).